# how to get a pdf file from coursehero?

Tags: python, web-scraping, download

can insert  code from Javascript or something else?I found the code on Python, is it giving something or working?to get a pdf file from coursehero?

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.3987.78 Safari/537.36'
}

data = {
    "client": "web",
    "query": "scrape",
    "view": "list_w",
    "filters": {
        "type": ["document"],
        "doc_type": [],
    },
    "sort": "relevancy",
    "limit": 20,
    "offset": 0,
    "callout_types": ["textbook"]
}

response = requests.post(
    'https://www.coursehero.com/api/v2/search/', headers=headers, json=data)

data = response.json()

for result in data['results']:
    url = f"https://www.coursehero.com/file/{result['document']['db_filename']}"
    print(f"'{result['core']['title']}' URL: {url}")

    # Login and extract download URL from HTML
    #
    # response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    # soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
    # download_url = soup.select('...')
    #
    # OR
    #
    # Download file via direct HTTP request if URL is returned via XHR request
    #
    # download_url = 'https://www.coursehero.com/...'
    # requests.get(download_url, headers=headers)
```

Course Hero front-end sends POST request to https://www.coursehero.com/api/v2/search and renders search results from JavaScript.Just fetch JSON via an HTTP request. Full example. I don't have a paid account so the last part of the code is commented since it's a pseudo-code.